# Instructions for unmounting and detaching softlayers block endurance volume on Linux

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to backup and then restore a snapshot of SL's endurance volume. However, once I restore the endurance volume to snapshot, I could not see my volume I created before I took the snapshot of that volume.

The process I followed is:

1. Create files on the path my volume is mounted.
2. Take snapshot from SL UI (Take manual Snapshot)
3. Delete the files I created on the path my volume is mounted.
4. Restore the snapshot I created in step 2. (I do this from SL UI)
5. Check if the files I created are present on the path. However, I could not see those files coming back as a part of restore snapshot process.

Am I missing anything? Like detaching the volume? Or unmounting before I restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to documentation you need to unmount and detach the storage from host before restoring an snapshot, this described in [endurance-snapshots](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/endurance-snapshots), look for **"Restore my storage volume..."**.

And after restoring, the storage volume must be mounted and re-attached, I recommend to review [block-storage-linux](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/block-storage-linux)

**Unmount and detach storage**

As you can see in [block-storage-linux](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/block-storage-linux) to verify if block storage is connected you need to execute:

```
fdisk -l | grep /dev/mapper
```

This will return something like this:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/3600a0980383030523424457a4a695266: 73.0 GB, 73023881216 byte
The volume is now mounted and accessible on the host.
```

To **unmount** you just need to execute:

```
unmount /dev/mapper/3600a0980383030523424457a4a695266
```

If you created a mount point as described in **step 4** of **Create a file system (optional)**, you can try executing following commands:

```
unmount /dev/mapper/3600a0980383030523424457a4a695266 /PerfDisk

unmount  /PerfDisk
```

About detach, I recommend you to review [Revoke a host's access to Block Storage](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/endurance-provisioning)

If you are not able to unmount or you have some issues, I recommend you submit a ticket to get further assistance.

I hope this help you.

References:

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/endurance-snapshots

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/block-storage-linux

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/endurance-provisioning

Comment: Hi, I already checked the link for restoring a snapshot. It does has reference to the steps for unmounting and detaching the volume , but those references takes us to mounting and attaching link. So I would say those references are incorrect. Can you give me a valid link for steps to detach and unmount ?